# Testing for dir via ssh script - nothing happens

Tags: bash, shell-script, ssh, here-document

I usually run server scripts like this, with a here-document.

But when I test if a directory exists, the script continues even though the test fails -- why?

```bash
ssh $user@$ip /bin/bash <<SCRIPT

if [[ ! -d ~/.debfiles ]];then
  echo "Error: debfiles doesnt exist" 2> ~/error.txt
  exit 1
fi

SCRIPT
```

I run this from my local computer and the server in question is a VM.

Comment: You can verify that the test succeeds (there is no directory called `.debfiles` in the user's home directory) because you can _see_ the error message? Note that nothing will be written to the `error.txt` file because `echo` writes to standard output by default and you're redirecting its standard error stream (the file will still be truncated (emptied)).

Comment: Please clarify what the intended behaviour is and what it is in this code that you say is being executed even though it shouldn't be executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Kusalananda noted in his edit, the `<<` syntax you're referring to is called a [here document](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=bash).

As other comments have noted, the intent of your script is somewhat vague, but consider structuring your script something like this:

```
user=me
ip=myhost
dir=Test

if ssh "$user"@$ip /bin/bash << SCRIPT
[[ ! -d ~/"$dir" ]]
SCRIPT
then
  echo "Error: $dir doesnt exist"
  exit 1
fi

echo the script continues
```

That way:

```
$ ssh me@myhost rm -rf Test
$ ./test.sh
Error: Test doesnt exist
$ ssh me@myhost mkdir Test
$ ./test.sh 
the script continues
```

For a here document as simple as this example, a "here string" would also suffice, provided that `$dir` doesn't contain any uncooperative characters:

```
if ssh "$user"@$ip /bin/bash <<< "[[ ! -d ~/$dir ]]"
then
...
```

Comment: You don't need a heredoc at all. You can simply write `if ssh "$user@$ip" [ ! -d ~/$dir ]`. There are quoting issues with `~/$dir` in either case though: you'd need double quotes to protect it from the local shell but allow the `$dir` variable to be expanded, and single quotes on the remote to keep whatever it has become. So `if ssh "$user@$ip" "[ ! -d ~/'$dir' ]"`. And this still presupposes your directory name value doesn't contain a single quote

Comment: @ChrisDavies No, it's not **needed**, I simply used it because it was the topic of the OP.  But thank you.  I do take your point.

Answer (score -1):

You're running the `exit` on the remote server. The section running there exits, and so `ssh` ends and the remainder of whatever's local then continues.

You've not shown any part that "*continues even though the test fails*", either on the remote host or the local system, so we cannot test with confidence we're trying what you're trying.

Comment: I tested the user's code with an added statement after the `if` statement, and I could not get both the body of the `if` statement, with the `exit`, and my added statement to execute.  What would execute the remainder of the script according to you?

Comment: There's nothing else local given in the question. I'm assuming `ssh <<SCRIPT ... SCRIPT; echo something else`, where the OP wouldn't want `something else` to be output if the `exit 1` was triggered, @Kusalananda. (I know the syntax is off; I'm hoping you'll see the intent.)